# Mapbox Studio Draw Order

Tags: postgis, cartography, layers, mapbox, draw-order

I have made a map using Mapbox Studio. The map is made up of 2 map sources,

1. MapBox Streets
2. Custom Style - a PostGIS layer

I am having trouble working out how to set the draw order. I have tried the logic of setting it with the CartoCSS and also tried dragging layer "Data" down the list (image below) to affect the draw order and have had no luck because I can't drag the layers.

Any points from the Geo Ecosystem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I guess that is what you get for Gungahlin :-) In any case, you should be able to drag the square to change the order (see https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/manual/interface-tour/#layers_list)

Comment: Thanks @BradHards, well spotted ;-). I tried to get around it with tilemill but it's not loading for me at present. Mapbox github suggests this has been solved but no dice so far.

Answer (score 2):

I stumbled upon an old project that made use of the "layers" in the porject.yml file so I inserted my layers in the format noted below and was able to manage the draw order of features this way.

Note: The top of the list is the lowest layer and the last list item is draw on top of the preceding items.

`layers:
    - landuse
    - waterway
    - water
    - aeroway
    - data
    - barrier_line
    - building
    - landuse_overlay
    - tunnel
    - road
    - bridge
    - admin
    - country_label_line
    - country_label
    - marine_label
    - state_label
    - place_label
    - water_label
    - poi_label
    - road_label
    - waterway_label
    - housenum_label`

**Result of solution**
[image]